# Why is fetch always returning undefined here?

Tags: javascript, django, rest, fetch

I am working on a Unit Conversion API, and I am having a lot of issues with fetch(). My backend API is working, for example, when I call
`curl "http://localhost:8000/unitconv/convert?to=lb&from=kg&value=10"` I get the correct response:
`{"units": "lb", "value": 22.04623}`. Yet when I do the exact same thing with fetch(), this is what I get:
[image: Screenshot]
I have tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1 and I still cannot get past this "undefined". What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a curly bracket in the first then without a return so nothing is going to the second then . It should be

```
.then((response) => {return response.json()}).then(() => ...
```

Comment: Dang I can't believe it was something this dumb I should've noticed this, I'm too used to lisp right now and JS functional programming is something else dude.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply omit the curly brackets like this:

```
fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(() =>
```